# Send an email via mailchimp in drupal to a userlist created in views

Tags: 7, views, emails

I want to give my client the possibility to send an email to a self-composed userlist. Preferably I want to direct the client to a (views) page where he can compose this list based on a couple of exposed filterfields (role, location etc)

Is it possible to compose a userlist via views and hand this over to mailchimp with [mailchimp](http://drupal.org/project/mailchimp)?

Thanks in advance